# Difference between C# Test Project and C# Class library Project

Tags: c#

Whats the motivation behind using c# test project rather then c# class library project to hold my unit tests?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a special project type guid used in MSTest projects. This is probably done to let the unit tests be dicoverd faster (only needs to scan actual test projects).

Answer (score 7):

The test project will, by default, have all the `MSTest` references added for you automatically. Also some default examples, such as a simple example test, is created for you.

With the class project, you can build a test project from that too, but you manually have to add the `MSTest` references yourself. Not a major problem really, but the test project can save you time and hassle.

EDIT:

As noted in the comments, the big difference between the two project types is that, with a class project, you can choose whichever unit testing framework you like.

Comment: To help clarify, a `Test Project` IS a `Library`, just with some extra stuff added

Comment: A test project will have a special project type guid, and will not be recognized without it.

Comment: Is that all? I have also noticed some test list files are appearing in solution.

Comment: It should be noted that MSTest isn't the only testing framework available. [xUnit.net](http://xunit.codeplex.com/) is an example, and [this extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/463c5987-f82b-46c8-a97e-b1cde42b9099) provides integration with Visual Studio 2012/2013.

Comment: As I know there are some differences how tests integrate in TFS build infrastructure depending weather MST or not.

Comment: Just went through the project files of both project types. Project Type GUID in MS Test project seems to be the most imp. difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find too much information about this Test project subtype identified by {3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB} however, according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166488.aspx project subtypes can 
include customizations:

```
 - saving additional data in the project file,
 - adding or filtering items in the Add New Item dialog box,
 - controlling how assemblies are debugged and deployed,
 - and extending the project Property Pages dialog box.
```

Indeed right-clicking on Test project in context menu -> in "Add" submenu you can see test items "Unit Test", "Ordered Test", "Generic Test". Adding "Unit Test" generates a test class template for MSTest.

Also it contains additional data like:

```
<TestProjectType>UnitTest</TestProjectType>
<IsCodedUITest>False</IsCodedUITest>
```

So it seems that this project subtype is rather MSTest specific.

**So if not using MSTest (using xUnit for example) I prefer a class library.**

Additional argument maybe the fact that in .Net Core project flavoring (subtyping) is not desired way to do things and indeed .Net Core test templates are class libraries. See discussion: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/061aaf74-bb13-4646-9d69-064f6f1b8ef6/net-core-project-subtypes

**Bonus**: xUnit.net.TestGenerator extension generates a Test project subtype if you don't select existing project (probably because it's just an xUnit adapter for VS generation tool)